# Infinite scroll for currency list

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, pagination

I made infinite scroll for a currency (in the code below: *valute*) list. The currency list is fetched via an AJAX-request from a remote server. After it starts the script displays 10 records. After the user scrolls it adds another set of records into the page.

```js
window.onscroll = function () {
    var B = document.body, 
            DE = document.documentElement,
            O = Math.min (B.clientHeight, DE.clientHeight); 

    if (!O) {
        O = B.clientHeight;
    }

    var S = Math.max (B.scrollTop, DE.scrollTop),
            C = Math.max (B.scrollHeight, DE.scrollHeight);

    if (O + S == C) {
        console.log('add');
        start = step;
        step += step;
        constructValute(start, step);
    }   
}

var start = 0, 
        step = 10;
var valuteArr = [],
        valuteArrLength = 0;

function constructValute(start, end) {
    var bodyEl = document.getElementById('body'),
            valuteArrLength = valuteArr.length;

    for(i = start; i < end; i++) {
        var tpl = document.getElementById('item');
      var itemEl = document.createElement('div');     

      if(i < valuteArrLength) {
          var CharCode = valuteArr[i].CharCode;
          var Name = valuteArr[i].Name;
          var Value = valuteArr[i].Value;

            tpl_ = tpl.innerHTML.replace('__CharCode__', CharCode)
                                                    .replace('__Name__', Name)
                                                    .replace('__Value__', Value);

          itemEl.className = 'item';
          itemEl.innerHTML = tpl_;
          bodyEl.appendChild(itemEl);
      } else {
        console.log('stopeed add')
        break;
      }

    }
};

function ajaxReq() {
    var this_ = this;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js');
    xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var responseText = xhr.responseText;
        var responseTextParsed = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var vauteList = responseTextParsed.Valute;

      //console.log('responseTextParsed is ', JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      console.log('valute list is ', vauteList);

      var valuteArr = [],
            i = 0;

        for(var prop in vauteList) {
            valuteArr[i] = vauteList[prop];
            ++i;              
            };

            valuteArrLength = valuteArr.length;
            console.log(valuteArrLength, valuteArr);

            this_.valuteArr = valuteArr;
      constructValute(0, step);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
    }
    };
    xhr.send(); 
};

ajaxReq();
```

```css
body{
    padding: 0px;
}

    .item{
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

        .item-inner{
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            .left{
                width: 90px;
                height: 90px;
                float: left;
                font-size: 2em;
                font-weight: bold;
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;                
            }

            .right{
                width: calc(100% - 100px);
                float: right;
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: flex-start;
                align-items: center;        
                min-height: 90px;       
            }

                .line{
                    width: 100%;
                }
```

```html
<body id="body">
        <script id="item" type="text/template">
                <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="left">__CharCode__</div>
                    <div class="right">
                            <div class="line name">__Name__</div>
                            <div class="line value">__Value__</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </script>
</body>
```

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/RkgdHdsqJqRD7oe1YQaL?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.onscroll` should be throttled. [See more info here](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/).

---

```
if (xhr.status === 200) {
    /* main code*/
} else {
    /*error handling*/
}
```

This could be improved like this:

```
if (xhr.status !== 200) {
    /*error handling*/
    return;
}
/* main code*/
```

The same is true for `if(i < valuteArrLength)`

[Read more about that here](http://wiki.c2.com/?GuardClause).

---

My personal opinion: one letter variable names are hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest reading [this article](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/). It has great advice about speeding up javascript code that interacts with the HTML elements of the page.

#### DOM lookups and variables

Taking the advice of that article mentioned above, put the code in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) so the variables declared will only be available to the functions in this code, and avoid conflicting with other variables elsewhere.

Then wait for the DOM to load by using [document.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) <sup>1</sup> to subscribe to the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event. Once that has happened, run the queries to get the elements needed - e.g. `document.body`, `document.getElementById('item')` (especially since that doesn't need to happen inside the *`for`* loop within `constructValute()`). Also, because the `<body>` tag has the **id** attribute set to *body*, `document.getElementById('body')` is equivalent to `document.body` so that extra variable can be eliminated.

```
(function() {
    var bodyEl, tpl;
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      bodyEl = document.body;//document.getElementById('body');
      tpl = document.getElementById('item');
      //..rest of calls once DOM has loaded: add scroll handler, call ajaxReq()
    });

    //other functions like constructValute, ajaxReq
}());
```

#### Adding Scroll handler

One can use [window.addEventListener('scroll')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) also to add a scroll handler - that can also go in the callback to theDOMContentLoaded event. This allows for multiple functions to be called during a scroll, unlike assigning `window.onscroll`.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(scrollEvent) {
    var B = bodyEl,
      DE = document.documentElement,
      O = Math.min(B.clientHeight, DE.clientHeight);
});
```

#### Adding items from the AJAX response to the array

This code:

```
var valuteArr = [],
        i = 0;

    for(var prop in vauteList) {
        valuteArr[i] = vauteList[prop];
        ++i;              
        };
```

Could be simplified using [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?), thus reducing the need for the iterator value `i`. Actually, I removed the variable `valueArr` inside the callback function and referenced the one outside the callback function, thus reducing the need for that extra variable, as well as `_this`.

```
Object.values(vauteList).forEach(function(obj) {
    valuteArr.push(obj);
});
```

See updated plunker [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/cR1bAQ9mvdp4JkYB6jcR/0).

<sup>1</sup> **Note** - not supported by IE 8 or earlier - [read more about using attachEvent in that case here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent)